# TestCase with list or params

Tags: c#, nunit, testcase, testcasedata

I am trying to write a testcase that takes a string and expects the string split up. I cannot initialize a `List` in a `TestCase`, so I tried using `TestCaseSource` with a `params` argument, however I get

> Wrong number of arguments provided

Is there any way for me to accomplish my end goal?

```
public IEnumerable<TestCaseData> blah
{
 get
 {
  yield return new TestCaseData("hello World", "h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d");
 }
}

[TestCaseSource("blah")]
public void testmethod(String orig, params String[] myList)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though both your `testmethod` and `TestCaseData` constructor take `params`, `TestCaseData` interprets `params` differently: it tries to map them one-to-one to the parameters of the method being tested. In your case, NUnit expects a `testmethod` with 12 parameters, but your method has only two. This causes the error that you see.

To fix this problem, you need to change the constructor call as follows:

```
yield return new TestCaseData(
    "hello World"
,   new[] {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"}
);
```

Now you are passing only two arguments, the second one being an array that must be passed to your `params String[] myList`.

Comment: I swear I tried that and it yelled at me about the object initializer....maybe I am just going crazy. Thanks...it works now!